Rails 7.1 redirect_to(Shibboleth Logout) is not working
I am not sure how to debug Rails 7.1, redirect_to() not working vs in Rails 3.2 the same exact code works.
Working Example
Within Rails 3.2, I have a Controller action "logout" that contains the below and logs me out of Shibboleth:
redirect_to('/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://login.edu/logout')
Below is Chrome console snapshot of a successful Shibboleth Logout.

Unsuccessful Shibboleth Logout Example
Within Rails 7.1, I have a Controller action "logout" that contains the below and when triggered just goes to the root route of the application.
redirect_to('/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://login.edu/logout')
Below is Chrome console snapshot of the unsuccessful Shibboleth Logout. Unsuccessful in that when I click the logout link I get redirected to the app's Main Menu (root path). What should happen is Shibboleth logout page. I get no errors from browser "console".

Below is a Chrome console snapshot when I hover over the Logout link. I have added rack-cors gem (which I have never needed in the past) and added config to allow GET, POST, PATCH, or PUT requests from any origin on any resource.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why Rails 7.1 redirect_to() no longer works?
Thank you

Can you provide some details on what "no longer works" means? Do you receive an error? Where does the page land? What does the controller action that processes the redirect look like? etc. Comparing rails 3.2. to rails 7.1 does not provide a lot to go on here as the changes made across 4 major versions (and nearly 12 years) are going to be substantial.

@engineersmnky thank you for your response. I have updated my post/question with more information. If you would like a snapshot of the 'logout' Controller action I can add it if my added information isn't helpful. Let me know, please.
